# Floating two texts next to each other and centering both of them

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following by CSS

I have two text that need to be next to each other.
Example: the two phone numbers to be on the right side of the "phone"

Phone: 301xxxxx

301xxxxx

I can do this using two div and floating one to the left. But I also want both of them to be centered as well. What would be the best way to structure this?

Comment: well i tried to add these two divs between another div and add the style (tex-align:center;) to the main one but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

**html:**

```
<div class="blah">
  <div>
    Phone:
  </div>
  <div>
    301xxxxx<br>
    301xxxxx
  </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**css:**

```
​.blah {
    text-align:center
}
.blah > div {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BvFnb/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 2 divs next to each other and then centering them to the page?

Possibly

Set width to the two divs as well as text align center to the text inside?

```
<div id="outter">
<div id="div1"> phone 1</div>
<div id="div2"> phone 2</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

css

#outter{
width: 400px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#div1, #div2{
width: 50%;
float: left;
text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then put them into parent `div` which is centered.

To center block elemnts like `div`, we have to set it's `width:` and `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LRuZp/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with table structure:

```
<tr>
    <td>phone</td>
    <td>301xxxx</td><br />
    <td>301xxxx</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try to stay away from tables as much as you can, unless its an absolute must.